# Seemingly random program failure at end of completion C++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, dynamic-arrays

**Warning:** I understand if anyone may want to stop reading now, this post contains ~275 lines of code across 6 files (although nothing very complex)! I realize this is usually a bad thing to do, but it's a last ditch effort as I've put cout's in everything method showing none of them crash or do anything that I wouldn't expect, researched implementation of the standard methods I'm using, and ran this code with a huge variety of inputs but sometimes it runs successfully, other times it fails (after finishing everything). I can't find any pattern or broken code segment.

The program simulates a type of shop with a single server allowing customers to order one of two things and there is a waiting line. The user inputs the simulation length, customer arrival probability per time unit (minute), and the time it takes for each item to be made. After running, the program then prints out a few statistics - total wait time (excluding those remaining in line), total customers served, and average wait time.

Even with long simulations (100,000 minutes) I've seen successful and failed runs (again, only failing after simulation completion). At first I thought it looked like using (>= 1) for arrival probability (customer arrives each minute) always worked, but have since noticed those failing. If anything, it seems fairly high arrival (> ~.8) and very low (<= ~.01) arrival probabilities crash the least often in long simulations, but still can sometimes in short ones. Very odd!

Whenever it *does* crash, the debugger shows the program counter stopping at the closing brace of queueType's destructor, but this destructor seems extrememly standard to me, and the same syntax has worked with other classes that allocate memory on the heap with their constructors? I feel like the answer must be something fairly basic that is eluding me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, code follows:

**queueType.h:**

```
#ifndef QUEUETYPE_H
#define QUEUETYPE_H
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

template<class Type>
class QueueType {
public:
    QueueType();
    ~QueueType();
    QueueType(const QueueType& other);
    Type& getFront() {return queueArray[front];}
    int getNumElements() const {return numElements;}
    void reposition();
    void addElement(Type);
    bool isEmpty() const {return numElements == 0;}
    bool isFull() const {return SIZE == numElements;}
    void updateWaitTimes(Type*&, int&, int&);

    QueueType<Type>& operator=(const QueueType other);

    friend void swap(QueueType& first, QueueType& second) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(first.front, second.front);
        swap(first.back, second.back);
        swap(first.numElements, second.numElements);
        swap(first.queueArray, second.queueArray);
    }
private:
    static const int SIZE = 25;
    int front, back, numElements;
    Type *queueArray;
};

template<class Type>
QueueType<Type>::QueueType() {
    queueArray = new Type[SIZE];
    front = back = numElements = 0;
}

template<class Type>
QueueType<Type>::~QueueType() {
    delete [] queueArray;
}

template<class Type>
QueueType<Type>::QueueType(const QueueType& other):
        queueArray(new Type[SIZE]),
        front(other.front),
        back(other.back),
        numElements(other.numElements)
{
    std::copy(other.queueArray, other.queueArray + SIZE, queueArray);
}

template<class Type>
void QueueType<Type>::reposition() {
    front = (front + 1) % SIZE;
    back = (back + 1) % SIZE;
    numElements--;
}

template<class Type>
void QueueType<Type>::addElement(Type newElement) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        queueArray[0] = newElement;
        front = back = 0;
        numElements = 1;
    } else {
        back = (back - 1) % SIZE;
        queueArray[back] = newElement;
        numElements++;
    }
}

template<class Type>
void QueueType<Type>::updateWaitTimes(Type*& element, int& position, int& counter) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        element = NULL;
    } else {
        if (position == 0) {
            position = front;
        }
        element = &queueArray[position];
        position = (position + 1) % SIZE;
    }
    if (counter == numElements) {
        element = NULL;
    }
    counter++;
}

template<class Type>
QueueType<Type>& QueueType<Type>::operator=(const QueueType other) {
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
#endif  /* QUEUETYPE_H */
```

**customerType.h:**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMERTYPE_H
#define CUSTOMERTYPE_H

class CustomerType {
public:
    CustomerType();
    CustomerType(int, int);
    ~CustomerType();
    CustomerType(const CustomerType& other);
    void incrementWaitTime() {waitTime++;}
    int getArrivalTime() const {return arrivalTime;}
    int getWaitTime() const {return waitTime;}

    CustomerType& operator=(const CustomerType& other);
private:
    int ID, arrivalTime, waitTime;
};

#endif  /* CUSTOMERTYPE_H */
```

**customerType.cpp:**

```
#include "customerType.h"

CustomerType::CustomerType() {
    waitTime = arrivalTime = ID = 0;
}

CustomerType::CustomerType(int arrivalTime, int ID) {
    this->arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    this->ID = ID;
    waitTime = 0;
}

CustomerType::~CustomerType() {
}

CustomerType::CustomerType(const CustomerType& other) {
    waitTime = other.waitTime;
    arrivalTime = other.arrivalTime;
    ID = other.ID;
}

CustomerType& CustomerType::operator=(const CustomerType& other) {
    waitTime = other.waitTime;
    arrivalTime = other.arrivalTime;
    ID = other.ID;
    return *this;
}
```

**serverType.h:**

```
#ifndef SERVERTYPE_H
#define SERVERTYPE_H

#include "customerType.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

class serverType {
public:
    serverType();
    ~serverType();
    serverType(const serverType& other);
    bool isFree() const {return (status == "free");}
    void setCustomer(CustomerType& newCustomer, int& transactionTime);
    void decrementTransactionTime();

    serverType& operator=(const serverType& other);
private:
    std::string status;
    int transactionTime;
    CustomerType currentCustomer;
};

#endif  /* SERVERTYPE_H */
```

**serverType.cpp:**

```
#include "serverType.h"

serverType::serverType() {
    status = "free";
    transactionTime = 0;
}

serverType::~serverType() {
}

serverType::serverType(const serverType& other) {
    status = other.status;
    transactionTime = other.transactionTime;
    currentCustomer = other.currentCustomer;

}

void serverType::setCustomer(CustomerType& newCustomer, int& transactionTime) {
    currentCustomer = newCustomer;
    this->transactionTime = transactionTime;
    status = "busy";
}

void serverType::decrementTransactionTime() {
    transactionTime--;
    if (transactionTime == 0)
        status = "free";
}

serverType& serverType::operator=(const serverType& other) {
    status = other.status;
    transactionTime = other.transactionTime;
    currentCustomer = other.currentCustomer;
    return *this;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "queueType.h"
#include "serverType.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int simulationTime, coneTime, shakeTime, currentTime = 0;
    int customerID = 1, totalWaitTime = 0, customersServiced = 0;
    double arrivalProb;

    cout << "Time-driven ice cream shop simulation" << endl
            << "Enter the following information to begin:" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Length of simulation (in minutes): ";
    cin >> simulationTime;
    cout << endl << "Probability of customer arrival each minute (example: 0.25): ";
    cin >> arrivalProb;
    cout << endl << "Minutes to make an ice cream cone: ";
    cin >> coneTime;
    cout << endl << "Minutes to make a shake: ";
    cin >> shakeTime;
    cout << endl << endl;

    QueueType<CustomerType> Line;
    serverType server;
    float chance;
    srand(time(0) % INT_MAX);

    while (currentTime < simulationTime) {
        chance = float (rand())/RAND_MAX;
        if (chance < arrivalProb) {
            if (!Line.isFull()) {
                Line.addElement(CustomerType(currentTime, customerID));
                customerID++;
            } else {
                cout << "Customer #" << customerID 
                        << " came during a full line and left!" << endl;
                customerID++;
            }
        }
        if (server.isFree() && (!Line.isEmpty())) { //going with 40% shake, 60% cone
            customersServiced++;
            if (chance < 0.4) {
                server.setCustomer(Line.getFront(), shakeTime);
            } else {
                server.setCustomer(Line.getFront(), coneTime);
            }
            totalWaitTime += Line.getFront().getWaitTime();
            Line.reposition();
        } else if (!server.isFree()) {
            server.decrementTransactionTime();
            CustomerType *customerPointer = new CustomerType();
            int position = 0, counter = 0;
            Line.updateWaitTimes(customerPointer, position, counter);
            while (customerPointer != NULL) {
                (*customerPointer).incrementWaitTime();
                Line.updateWaitTimes(customerPointer, position, counter);
            }
            delete customerPointer;
        }
        currentTime++;
    }
    cout << endl << endl << "Simulation complete." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Total wait time: " << totalWaitTime << endl
            << "Customers serviced: " << customersServiced << endl
            << "Average wait time: " << float (totalWaitTime) / customersServiced;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the queueType copy constructor/overloaded =/destructor never getting called until the destructor does once in the very end. I also know I don't need to have a customerType (currentCustomer) as one of serverType's private members, but just for the sake of realism.

Comment: Please make a short self-contained example. In doing so, you're likely to find the problem. http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Wow.  1) How about giving us the data that you used to recreate the problem instead of cin statements.  

2) How well did you unit test your QueueType class?  To use it in such a program requires it to be practically bullet-proof.

Comment: 1) Ive tried times anywhere from 10 -> 100,000 (usually 1 per order of magnitude), arrival probabilities from 0 to 1 (0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.9, 0.99, 1), and shake/cone times from 1, 1 to 4, 4 all cases
2) I mostly used cout's in methods that change any variables, showing me they were changing in the way I thought, wanted a circular array

Comment: @Cogwheel - not sure how to make a shorter example that uses each class besides just using very small inputs? (which I've tried many times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW. Just finally realized the reason it was crashing was how I changed back around in queueType::reposition and queueType::addElement, in reposition I didn't need to move back at all since it's just called after someone leaves the front, and in my add I meant to move back BACK one but used - not + and moved it forward...program fixed. Thank you for answers/comments

Answer (score 2):

You are mismanaging memory here:

```
CustomerType *customerPointer = new CustomerType();
int position = 0, counter = 0;
Line.updateWaitTimes(customerPointer, position, counter);
```

You are allocating memory for customerPointer.  Then you change the value of what customerPointer points to in the Line.updateWaitTimes function.  Then you do this:

```
delete customerPointer;
```

So what you allocated and what you deleted have different values.  You're corrupting the heap by attempting to delete an address that doesn't start at the beginning of the dynamically allocated block.

If what you are deleting *is* a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, i.e. you designed it this way, but is a "different" pointer than the original you started out with, then you need to rewrite your code so you're not doing this "pointer dance" between customerPointer and the Line.updateWaitTimes function.

This is just one of probably many issues with your code you need to fix.  One fix is to quit with the manual memory mamagement within your main() function.  Learn to write code that minimizes or eliminates the usage of raw naked pointers.  Yes, your QueueType class must do memory management, sure, but that doesn't mean your main() has to do this also.

Also, your QueueType class maintains its own memory that should not be fooled around with by an outside entity.  Look at your QueueType::updateWaitTimes function -- why is it giving a pointer to the passed in "element" pointer?  You then use this pointer to your internal queue and finagle with it in main(), which gives disastrous results.  Writing code like this means that you haven't totally grasped the meaning of "encapsulation".

Comment: Oh was thinking this was the correct way to free what was allocated for that pointer. Is there a way to still do this procedure with a simple fix? I wouldn't manually manage memory in main but my goal was for queueType to be completely reusable and not have to know anything about customerType, so all it is doing with updateWaitTimes function is moving the pointer to the next element until it has covered everything in its array, then I would update each customer back in main. Why does changing just the address that a pointer contains (element = &queueArray[position];) change anything about it?

Comment: No. Read my updated comment. You should *never* have the outside entity take charge of how your QueueType class handles memory.

Comment: When you allocate with "new", a value is returned.  Come heck or high water, you better retain that value.  The reason why is that you'll need that same value when it comes time to call "delete".  Note that I stated "value" and not "pointer".

Comment: Your QueueType is supposed to be generic. What I think you're trying to do is take QueueType and give it the power to know everything about what your main() program is doing. This is wrong. QueueType() has a public interface -- any functions using QueueType has the public interface to work with *and nothing else*.  One change is to get rid of the "updateWaitTimes" function from QueueType -- it shouldn't be there at all.

Comment: Oh ok, if you have to retain a value doesn't that mean you should never use: pointerName = &somethingElse after allocating heap space with pointerName? Is there any different way to update each customer's wait time in queueType's array both without using a pointer from main and not allowing queueType to directly access customerTypes?

Comment: Remove the updateWaitTimes from QueueType.  What you want to do is iterate through the queue (if that's possible), get the object at each queue location, and do whatever you want with the object.  You don't do this work inside the QueueType object -- you do this outside the class in a loop of some sort that goes from the head of the queue to the back of the queue.

Comment: That's just what I want to do, will have to make that change, but is it possible to iterate through queue from main without having both a getFront() accessor and others indicating how many are in the queue, where the back is, etc. in queueType since its array is private? My assuming those would be needed is the reason why I made queueType::updateWaitTimes instead

Comment: Just realized I was completely screwing up how I moved the back element in queueType around was making it sometimes crash o_O but thanks a lot for giving me a better understanding of manual mem management and design

Answer (score 1):

This line likely as problem, as it can leave back as negative

```
back = (back - 1) % SIZE;
```

you probably meant something like

```
back = (SIZE + back - 1) % SIZE;
```

Comment: It seems like it must always be positive, smallest case is back starts at 0 so back = (0 - 1) % SIZE would still give 24?

Comment: But SIZE is a static constant int set at 25, so (0 - 1) % 25:
https://www.google.com/#q=-1+modulo+25

Comment: It comes down to how C++ defines it:  I'd suggest you try this bit of code:   std::cout <<  -1 % 25 << "\n";

Comment: Oh that's odd, unfortunately changing to
    back = (SIZE + back - 1) % SIZE;
still causes crashing, but thanks I didn't know C++ worked with modulo in that way

Comment: Made me think, it was part of the problem but it should have instead been back = (back + 1) % SIZE; I have no idea why I was moving it backwards, thanks for help